# Why do github-webhook payloads contain 'zen'?

Tags: github-webhook

I've noticed in the ping section [here](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/#ping-event-payload) that they contain `Random string of GitHub zen`. Whats the point of these strings?

Comment: clearly having a little fun... wouldn't you?